# New version of Hakyll and Expected type : Map [Char] a0

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I wrote a context definition with Hakyll like this :

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
....
mathCtx :: Context String
mathCtx = field "mathjax" $ \item -> do
  metadata <- getMetadata $ itemIdentifier item
  return $ if "mathjax" `M.member` (metadata)
           then "<script type=\"text/javascr ...  script>"
           else ""
```

It worked well until I migrated to `Debian 9`, `Hakyll 4.9.2.0` and `GHC 8.0.1`. Now, I have this error message when compiling :

```
• Couldn't match type ‘unordered-containers-0.2.7.1:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                         text-1.2.2.1:Data.Text.Internal.Text
                         aeson-0.11.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value’
                 with ‘M.Map [Char] a0’
  Expected type: M.Map [Char] a0
    Actual type: Metadata
• In the second argument of ‘M.member’, namely ‘(metadata)’
  In the expression: "mathjax" `M.member` (metadata)
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘if "mathjax" `M.member` (metadata) then
         "<script type=\"text/javascr ...  script>"
     else
         ""’
```

**Do you know what is going wrong now with my function and how to correct this ?**

Comment: Hackage doesn't know of a Hakyll 0.9.2.0, and it would be really old if it did exist. Did you mean 4.9.2.0? Furthermore, do you know what you upgraded from?

Comment: have you tried adding `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings -#}` Metadata is a type alias for `HashMap Text Value` and the compiler complains about the "mathjax" being a `String`

Comment: Migrated from what to your current choice?